# Colorbar limits that are different from the normalization

Tags: matplotlib, limit, colorbar

I'm trying to make a scatter plot with colorbar where "0" is transparent. It's important that data that is zero has a transparent scatter point, but I don't want this transparent color bin to show up in my colorbar. I would like to limit the range of my colorbar legend to (1,14). clim(0, 14) doesn't do the job for me.

```
plt.figure()
cmaplist = plt.get_cmap('jet')(range(256))
cmaplist[:,-1] = [0] + list(np.ones(len(cmaplist[:-1])))
map_object = mpl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(name='agn_map', colors=cmaplist)
plt.register_cmap(cmap=map_object)
bounds = np.linspace(0, 14, 15)
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, 256)

x, y, z = np.random.uniform(0, 10, 50), np.random.uniform(0, 10, 50), np.random.randint(0, 14, 50)
plt.scatter(x, y, c=z, cmap='agn_map', norm=norm, s=25, marker="*")
plt.xlabel('V-J restframe mag', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('U-V restframe mag', fontsize=12)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

I'd like to cut off the lowest color bin from the bar:

[image: out]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question: this code gives me the result I wanted.

```
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize 
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.figure()
cmaplist = plt.get_cmap('jet')(range(256))
cmaplist[:,-1] = [0] + list(np.ones(len(cmaplist[:-1])))
map_object = mpl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(name='agn_map', colors=cmaplist)
plt.register_cmap(cmap=map_object)

x, y, z = np.random.uniform(0, 10, 50), np.random.uniform(0, 10, 50), np.random.randint(0, 14, 50)
plt.scatter(x, y, c=z, cmap='agn_map', norm=Normalize(vmin=1,vmax=14), s=25, marker="*") #update
bounds = np.linspace(1, 14, 14)
plt.colorbar(ticks=np.arange(1,15), drawedges=True, boundaries=bounds) # update

plt.xlabel('V-J restframe mag', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('U-V restframe mag', fontsize=12)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How does the introduction of a library of normalization and minimum and maximum values solve your challenge? The following code raises only the rows to be added and the rows to be updated.

```
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize #add
plt.scatter(x, y, c=z, cmap='agn_map', norm=Normalize(vmin=1,vmax=14), s=25, marker="*") #update
plt.colorbar(ticks=np.arange(1,15)) # update
```

[image]

Comment: Great! But is there a way to keep the discreteness of the bar as well?